# During simulation, why do flip-flops take the value preceding the transition while conditional(if) statements take the value after the transition?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

As you can see in the cursor below, the if statement looks AFTER the transition (it sees rst = 0 and thus sets a equal to in) rather than seeing rst = 1.

BUT it can also be seen that c takes the value of a BEFORE the transition.

I am wondering why this is. Suppose you want to gate a register with an enable that is delayed on clock cycle, then you can not use if (enable_delayed) because (ideally) the falling transition will happen on the rising edge of the clock and thus not be detected in simulation.

I have not had success finding my problem online. It is hard to explain and search for. Thanks for the help.
[image]

Code:

```
module project_test 
( input logic clk, rst, 
    input logic in,
    output logic a,
    output logic b,
    output logic c
);

always@(posedge clk) 
    if(rst) a <= 1'b0;
    else    a <= in;
always@(posedge clk) 
    if(a) b <= a;
always@(posedge clk) 
    c <= a;

endmodule: project_test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be you are setting `rst` earlier than you think and it is already `0` when the logic inside the module observes the positive `clk` edge.

If you were to set `rst` to `0` as a result of a `@(posedge clk)` things would work as you expect, but I suspect `rst` is being changed in parallel with `clk`.

When debugging this sort of thing, I always try to delay the assignment of the values. That is, in your module here replace `<=` with `<= #1` .

Comment: Here is the testbench, they are updated at the same time: https://gist.github.com/MahmoudMaarouf/e8bf9c28868d9bf34b57f2706bb1c85d
I appreciate the input.

Comment: In that case, as suspected, the value of `rst` has already changed by the time the module recognizes the positive edge of `clk`. That is, the module samples `rst` from BEFORE the observed transition in `clk` and sees a value of `0`. Specifically, `rst` is `0` AFTER and (just) BEFORE the `posedge` event.

Answer (score -1):

rst is a wire (an input port is a wire, at least in verilog), so value is continuously assigned to it. So when it was sampled during the positive edge of the clock, its value is already 0.
'a' on the other hand is a reg(a flipflop) so its value when it was sampled on the positive edge of the clock is still its previous value. Its value will only change 'right after the clock'. That's why 'c' still gets the previous value of 'a'.
I think that's what's happening here.