# RTL if statements not matching with simulation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am struggling to understand why the output flickers between 0 and 1, when the output should constantly remain 0 since the reduction OR gate of 000 is 0 not 1.

When I tried a different bit width, the problem suddenly disappeared. However, I would like to know what is going on rather than relying on randomness for correctness.

**project_test .sv**

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module project_test 
( input logic clk, rst, 
    input logic in,
    output logic [2:0] c
);

logic [2:0] out;


always@(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
    if(rst) 
        out <= 'b0;
    else if(in) begin
        if(|out)
            out <= 'b0;
    end
    else
        out <= out + 1'b1;
end

assign c = out;

endmodule: project_test
```

**testbench.sv**

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module testbench;
 logic clk, rst;
 logic in;
 logic [2:0] c;

project_test project_test(
.clk(clk),
.rst(rst),
.in(in),
.c(c)
);

initial begin
clk = 0;
rst = 1;
in = 0  ;
#30
rst = 0;
#20;
in = 1;
#500;
rst=1;
#100ns;
$stop();
end

always@(clk) begin
  #10ns clk <= !clk;
end

endmodule
```

**Simulation output:**
[image]

**RTL viewer:**
[image]

Comment: I tried it on different simulators and could not reproduce your issue.  Cadence for some reason did not want to trigger clocks here,  thought it should have in my opinion. All other worked with no problem. I vote to close it as non-reproducible.

Comment: @Serge Serge, I believe this issue is dependent on your simulator and the way you write the code. I believe it is similar to a previous post of mine:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68538852/during-simulation-why-do-flip-flops-take-the-value-preceding-the-transition-whi/68708774#68708774

It all depends on the verilog event queue.

Comment: @Serge Probably only works if the simulator "sees" a transition on clock at time 0 (X to 0). This jumpstarts the always block. Otherwise, it hangs.

Comment: @TudorTimi no, there is something else going on. Cadence does not see '1->0' transition in this case. somehow it does not re-evaluate the always block on the event.

Answer (score 1):

That is an improper way to generate a clock signal in the testbench.  You should not have the `clk` signal in the sensitivity list because it keeps re-triggerring the `always` block.  Your clock generator potentially adds events to the Verilog event queue, which can cause odd behavior.  In fact, when I ran your code on the Cadence simulator, I did not see the clock toggling at all.

This is a more standard way to generate a clock:

```
always begin
    #10ns clk = !clk;
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using a very verbose implementation. Why can't you do something like below.

```
always@(posedge clk or posedge rst) 
begin
if(rst) 
    out <= 'd0;
else
    out <= (in) ? 'd0 : (out + 1'b1);  
end
```